# titanium open new url

Tags: javascript, html, css, macos, titanium

I would like to open a new url in the default browser when the user clicks on an image.
I have looked into the Titanium.Platform.openURL but don't know how to use it.

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Ti.Platform.openURL("http://m.google.com"); //replace string lit with your url
```

Comment: The link needs to have http:// in front of it as this method is also used for calling ect.

Comment: Only works if the webpage you're opening doesn't have a strict SAME_ORIGIN policy

Answer (score 2):

You just pass the URL you want to open on the click event as the parameter to openUrl

Answer (score 1):

make sure the link has "http://" in front or it won't do anything